# Get bigger profile picture of facebook friends

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm simply trying to get a list of facebook friends that have my app, along with their profile picture in decent quality, something higher than the default 50x50 image i'm getting.

1) Doing a graph path `me/friends?fields=name,id,picture` gives me what i want but with the low quality picture

2) Doing something like `me/friends?fields=name,id,picture&type=large&redirect=false` does nothing unfortunately.

Checked pretty much every single SO post about getting the bigger profile picture, none of those methods work, all invalid graph paths, or they're outdated.  Please help!  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can ask for a bigger picture in your parameters, like this

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: ["fields":"id,email,name,picture.width(480).height(480)"]).startWithCompletionHandler({
```

Comment: AWESOME, thank you!!  Exactly what i was looking for.